# ¿Cómo realizar esta operacion? (Javascript, Prompt)

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando realizar un tercer prompt de Javascript que me permita realizar las operaciones a continuación. La premisa básica es que el tercer prompt funcione como la operación matemática a realizar. Adjunto el código

```
console.log("Info");

var d1= parseInt (prompt("Número 1"))

var d2= parseInt (prompt("Número 2"))

var d3= (prompt("Operación"))


function operaciones(d1,d2,d3) {   

    if(d3="suma"){console.log(d1+d2)}

    if(d3="resta"){console.log(d1-d2)}

    if(d3="multiplicacion"){console.log(d1*d2)}

    if(d3="division"){console.log(d1/d2)}    

    if(d3="raiz"){console.log(Math.sqrt(d1))}

    if(d3="potencia"){console.log(Math.pow(d1,d2))}

    if(d3="porcentaje"){console.log(d1*(d2/100))}

    if(d3="logaritmo"){console.log(Math.log(d1))}

    if(d3="diferencial"){console.log((d1+d2)/2)}

    operaciones(d1,d2,"sumar");
}
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a d3? Es un poco confusa tu pregunta, ¿Cuál es el error o comportamiento esperado?

Comment: No tengo ningún error pero d3 debería funcionar como el selector de operación. Lo que intento hacer es un tercer prompt que me permita seleccionar las operaciones.

Comment: ¿algo como un select dentro de un prompt? si es eso solo desde html, el prompt solo puede recibir caracteres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código compartido, aún cuando expresa la idea que mencionas, tiene algunos errores.

Todas las comparaciones las estás intentado hacer con un operador de asignación `=`, el operador de comparación es doble igual `==`

```
if(d3="suma")
```

Cambia a:

```
if(d3=="suma")
```

Por último, la llamada a la función `operaciones(d1,d2,"sumar");` se encuentra dentro de sí misma según el código que compartes, debe estar fuera para que sea invocada.

Comment: Con tus correcciones el código ha funcionado como lo esperado. Gracias